# Flutter - sub-tab navigation from another screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

User needs to be sent from a page to a specific tab (not the 1st one) on a different page with tabs in a similar way to how html does it by simply a hash sign and the relevant id, e.g.: site.com/page123/#tab5
What would be a good way of achieving the same in Flutter?

Comment: If you are using navigator with named routes, you'll need to actually parse them likewise. If not, well, you can just pass as argument of the new screen the tab index that you want to display by default.

Comment: How do you properly "pass as an argument" of the new screen the tab index.

Comment: I have also a same question